# How do I print a single string into multiple lines?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am using C#, ASP. I have a single string that looks like the following:

```
"["Fruit:Apple","Animal:Dog", "Food:Pizza"]"
```

How do I format it so I can get it to print like the following:

> Fruit:Apple
>
> Animal:Dog
>
> Food:Pizza

Comment: You need a JSON parser.

Comment: I don't think that is valid JSON. The quotes are wrong.

Comment: An interesting function would be to pass a string of comma separated values (CSV) and get a valid JSON-format for it.  Of course, that would be a different question.

Comment: When asking a question, it's good to get your code working (or close to working) in the language you are working in and then copy/paste it into the question.  That "single string" is not a valid string.

Comment: Whoever edited my question missed an inverted comma right before Food. I fixed it up. @Flydog57

Comment: But, that's still not a legal C# string. You'd need to _escape_ your quotes: `"[\"Fruit:Apple\",\"Animal:Dog\", \"Food:Pizza\"]"`.  A quoted string can't contain unescaped quotes; otherwise, the existence of the embedded quote would end the string.

Answer (score 0):

That string isn't C#, and it isn't JSON.  So, let's turn it into a C# string (by escaping the quotes) and just parsing it using old-school, brute-force C#:

```
 var buffer = new StringBuilder("[\"Fruit: Apple\",\"Animal: Dog\", \"Food:Pizza\"]");
 buffer.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
 buffer.Replace("[", string.Empty);
 buffer.Replace("]", string.Empty);
 var results = buffer.ToString().Split(',');
 foreach (var s in results)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(s.Trim());
 }
```

which results in:

```
Fruit: Apple
Animal: Dog
Food:Pizza
```

If you don't like the embedded spaces, remove them (either from the input code or by using another `.Replace` call

Answer (score -1):

if the string is like this "[\"Fruit: Apple\",\"Animal: Dog\", \"Food:Pizza\"]"
Install NewtonSoft.Json package first

```
 string myString = "[\"Fruit: Apple\",\"Animal: Dog\", \"Food:Pizza\"]";
    var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(myString);
    myList.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```